# How different is breathing in wildfire smoke in urban areas compared to sitting by a campfire for a night?

Tags: health, environment

The air quality in the Bay Area is currently the worst in the world, due to the devastating Butte County wildfires. I understand smoke inhalation can cause inflammation and respiratory issues, especially with chronic exposure, but I'm wondering in actuality, how different is the exposure to wildfire smoke in urban areas (AQI 100-300) over the course of a few days, compared to sitting by a campfire for a night?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology in terms of SE Biology, but about air polution.

Comment: The effects of air pollution on the human body seems like biology to me. Plus, it is topical and relevant to every person who has ever been camping. I think it is an interesting question that I would like to know the answer to.

Comment: Generally one sits upwind of a campfire, so as not to breathe the smoke.  And if the wind shifts, everyone moves :-)